# 'TarFile' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python

I am trying to train a `KNeighborsClassifier` from `scikit-learn`, but having some trouble loading the training data from a tarfile.

Here is the code I have written:

```Python
#Part 1 ~ Q1

import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import tarfile

tar = tarfile.open(r'C:\Users\Calum Nairn\Downloads\enron1.tar.gz')
tar.extractall()
tar.close()

data_x = tar['spam']
data_y = tar['target']
classes = tar['target_names']

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(data_x,data_y,test_size=0.30,random_state=42) 

# Create the classifier
knnclassifier = KNeighborsClassifier()  

# Fitting the model on the train dataset
knnclassifier.fit(x_train,y_train)  

# Check the Performance on the training set  
pred_train = knnclassifier.predict(x_train)
train_accu= accuracy_score(pred_train,y_train)
print(f'The Accuracy on the train set is: {round(train_accu*100,2)}%')

# Check the Performance on the test set  
pred_test = knnclassifier.predict(x_test)
test_accu= accuracy_score(pred_test,y_test)
print(f'The Accuracy on the test set is: {round(test_accu*100,2)}%')
```

The error I get:

```Python
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-fdb7523b73d9> in <module>
     11 tar.close()
     12 
---> 13 data_x = tar['spam']
     14 data_y = tar['target']
     15 classes = tar['target_names']

TypeError: 'TarFile' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing a couple of steps here between extracting the tarfile and accessing the data, so let's break it down.

`tar` is a [`TarFile`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tarfile.html?highlight=tarfile#tarfile.TarFile) object, and it does not hold the contents of the tar nor of the individual files inside. It is basically a handle to an open file on the filesystem (these are usually called [file-like objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) in the Python world).

`tar.extractall()` places the individual files contained in the tarfile into the working directory. This does not modify `tar` object in any way, it still holds no actual file contents.

You are then trying to load data points as `tar['spam']`, `tar['target']` etc. `'TarFile' object is not subscriptable` means that your object `tar` of type `TarFile` does not support accessing its "items" by "names" like `'spam'`, because, as mentioned above, it does not have any "items" inside.

What you actually need to do is read those files you previously extracted.

```py
data_x_file = open('spam', 'r')
data_x_raw_text = data_x_file.read()
data_x_file.close()
```

You will then need to convert `data_x_raw_text` into a data structure suitable for `train_test_split`, like a list of data points. How you do that will depend on how the source data is formatted.

Also, `scikit-learn` or `numpy` most probably have some helpers for loading datasets so you don't have to open-load-convert manually, you should try searching
their docs.